# How to fetch a user's id from a database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a simple `PHP` web-application. And in that I want to get Id of user from the `mysql` database.

For that I have used session to store userID as soon as user in inserted in database:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['customer_id']=mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

But it always says that undefined index customer_id on other pages.It is working fine on localhost but not on live server.

Comment: Can you also paste where you have defined `$con` and your query?

Comment: Did you try print `mysqli_insert_id($con);` and what the result for that?

Comment: <?php

 $con=mysqli_connect("my_ip","","","test");
?>

Comment: this code is incomplete. post more code. from this code alone, something looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php): `mysqli_insert_id` *Returns the auto generated id used in the **latest** query*. If you don't run an insert query before starting session, then `mysqli_insert_id` will not return what you're looking for.

Rather, try searching for the user with information obtained upon user login, like the user's email address or username.

E.g.

`SELECT id FROM users WHERE users.username = userSuppliedEmail`

It goes without saying that you should use prepared statements or some similar technology for this query.

Comment: But it is working on localhost. As soon as i get id it is inserted into the table.

Comment: are you calling `session_start` on every page? BEFORE accessing `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Yes on the very first line of my PHP block

Comment: do you have access to [session save path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to check that the session is created?

Comment: How do i know i have access to the session save path?

Comment: you can get the path by running `ini_get('session.save_path')`.. then, you can list all files with [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). so, `$files = scandir(ini_get('session.save_path'))` should do it i think

Comment: correction above, it's "session.save_path" not "session_save_path"

Comment: ill post in an answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is preventing you from creating a session.

Before you do anything, where you declare `session_start`, do the following:

Instead of `session_start()` put:

```
$started = session_start();
echo "Session Started: " . ($started ? "YES" : "NO");
```

If PHP says the session is indeed started, make sure the session id is staying the same between requests. You can obtain the session id with:

```
echo session_id();
```

From request to request, the session id must be the same, unless it's expired, or deleted. If you get a session id on first page, but no session id on second page, then either `session_start` wasn't executed, or the session was not created.

Since you assured me `session_start` is executed, the next thing you need to do is verify that the session is indeed created, and written to a file on the server.

After you obtain the session id, (eg. `7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e`) you should check your sessions folder for a file named `7815696ecbf1c96e6894b779456d330e` (this is just an example, your file name will be different).

```
$sessionPath = ini_get('session.save_path'); // obtains the path to session
echo "Our session path is: $sessionPath <br/>";
$filesInSessionFolder = scandir($sessionPath); // obtain all files in session folder
if($filesInSessionFolder == false){
    echo "Could not access session folder<br/>";
}else{
    // display all files in the folder
    print_r($filesInSessionFolder);
}
```

Now make sure that the session id exists in the list.

Comment: Yes it is accessing mine c:/wamp/tmp folder and returning list of session files.

Comment: Session Started: YES  Our session path is: c:/wamp/tmp
Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => sess_0heprdm45va6pmputuninu7957 [3] => sess_4f986auq2p7jf9l20vagv92psrmemjdb [4] => sess_dvqju5v600j3gfh7a6r67jvhl2 [5] => sess_efoeaae0voallrbuj02ut785c1 [6] => sess_i38frub4dcgvij6vq3350espj1 [7] => sess_imc031rqg5bv444df3l7fde5a4 [8] => sess_rr19bh8qphfvaachubt21dcrr2 )

Comment: looks like sessions are working. problem might be elsewhere

Comment: you executed `echo session_id();` and you got `0`?

Comment: `c:/wamp/tmp` is that local or remote? you need to run this on live server. its very odd that the session_id is `0`, it's never supposed to return `0` but an empty string. are you using any third party libraries? any frameworks? do you have a custom session handler?

Comment: Yes I am running it on a live server.But when I run the  same program on localhost it works fine.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Oh! I was wrong it is giving 0heprdm45va6pmputuninu7957 as session_id